# what is the meaning of "the family dynamic" and "Textbook Case"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, american-english

I encountered the terms  “the family dynamic” and “Textbook Case” in the play *[The Pain and the Itch](http://www.steppenwolf.org/watchlisten/program-articles/detail.aspx?id=77)*  by Bruce Norris. I want to know what they mean.  At page 58:

> Clay: Kelly was abused.
>   Carol: Oh, Kelly! Ohhhhh.
>   Kelly: True.
>   Carol: I didn't know that! Oh, how awful.
>   Kelly: The family dynamic. Yeah. Textbook case.
>   Carol: Ohh, how horrible. I hope that's not true!
>   Clay: It is true. It absolutely is.
>   Carol: Ohh, ..."

Answer (score 6):

"Textbook case" is an expression, meaning an example of a class of situations that is so typical, it could be used in a textbook devoted to such situations.

"Family dynamic" just means what it says: the "dynamic" (that is, the way the people interact with each other) of the family.  So (for example) one person complains, which makes another family member angry, which means a third always has to play peacemaker, and so on.

Comment: Sorry, typos.  Fixed now.

Comment: Oops, sorry, looks like my edits stepped on yours. Feel free to revert me (and +1 for a clear, concise explanation).